# Why that stupid reputation system?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Seriously. I couldn't post images because I didn't have ten "reputation" points. Come on. I posted a link and then people who are able to edit had to turn it into an inline picture. Just, why?

Comment: To prevent spam?

Comment: It's right that spam should be prevented, but everyone can post links instead of pictures. And you can't post anything on this thing. Not this way.

Comment: the reason you can post -some- links (there is a limit too there) is so that someone with more rep can check them and insert the image.

Comment: Typically if you lack the rep, and its a properly hosted image, people are quite happy to edit it in - its an easy 2 reputation for low rep users, and a way to keep the site tidy for higher rep users.

Answer (score 16):

- To prevent spam (yes I stole that from Braiam).
- It will take you mere seconds to get 10 rep.
- As you stated: If you dump the link someone with more rep can edit it into an image for you.

Otherwise we all would be deleting porn and other malicious pictures.

Please take the [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) and you will better understand how askubuntu (or stackexchange sites in general) works.

It is not a bad system!

Comment: It took me more than a day to get 10 rep. Just saying...

Comment: Sorry, it took me 10 seconds; answering is the way to get reputation ;-) Ondanks dat: toch veel plezier met Ubuntu :)

Comment: @WOLFLΔMBERT I am sure you can live with "more than a day", not like it took you years. Just saying.

Comment: Spam rhymes with Braiam (I think)